# send email with vuejs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I want to send emails with laravel and vuejs. I wrote laravel controller function like below

```
Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'],['name', 'David'], function($message){
    $message->to('test123@gmail.com')->subject('Test Email');
    $message->from('testmail@gmail.com', 'David');
});
return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
```

and I wrote a vuejs send email function for the @click method

```
this.axios.get('https://techwizlanka/send', {
    body: JSON.stringify(this.user),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log("email sent");
})
.catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

I call this URL like this

```
Route::get('/send', 'MailController@sendMail');
```

But it shows this error message when clicking the send button.

> app.js:44786 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at VueComponent.sendMail (app.js:44786)
>       at invoker (app.js:34769)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (app.js:34568)

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Basically, I want to send an email when submitting a form with laravel and vuejs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send an email with Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149550/how-to-send-an-email-with-vuejs)

Comment: i used my domain mail server configuration for this. when i call my controller with url it works. but when i used vuejs send mail function it shows i mentioned error.

Comment: First of all you want to use post and not get

Answer (score 2):

Definitely it's because you are not calling `axios` properly. Please make sure what does `this` on `this.axios` refer to.

Assuming you installed *axios* using `npm install axios`. Then try to import and use the *axios* more or less as follow:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        user: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    click() {
        axios
        .get('https://techwizlanka/send', {
            body: JSON.stringify(this.user),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log("email sent");
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
    },
  },

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this method

```
axios.post(url, data)
      .then(response => {

})
```

and make your route post in your route/web.php

in using get method function not expecting a request but in your situation you pass a request.